# publickey error using cvs

Tags: mac, ssh, window-manager, unix

I'm trying to get a copy of the repository for scrotwm using their cvs repository, but I'm having some trouble. I'm running the pull according to this example: http://onethingwell.org/post/5609933530/scrotwm-osx.

Sadly, when I run the cvs pull I get the following error message:

```
Permission denied (publickey).
cvs [checkout aborted]: end of file from server (consult above messages if any)
```

I haven't managed to get anything else working with cvs, but it looks like an ssh error of some kind. My github is working fine, and I know how to set up new ssh keys for github, but I haven't been able to find anything similar for cvs. Any ideas on places I should look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be because scrotwm has been renamed to [spectrwm](https://opensource.conformal.com/wiki/spectrwm) and I'm guessing the old CVS repository has been removed.

As per the above link, you can clone the new git repository using either of the following:

```
    $ git clone git://opensource.conformal.com/spectrwm.git
    $ git clone https://opensource.conformal.com/git/spectrwm.git
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. Thought spectrwm was a fork of scrotwm, next step dwm on osx!